# Use url_id to find fan_page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm wondering if it's possible to use url id [see below] to find a fan page information in the link below.

```
{
  data: [
          {
             url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
              id: 24121414888,
            type: "link",
            site: "stackoverflow.com"
          }
        ]
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/11239244970

If you use the link id it throws an error like below:

```
{
  error: {
            message: "An access token is required to request this resource.",
            type: "OAuthException",
            code: 104
         }
}
```

If anyone knows of a good way to do it, I would greatly appreciate it. Can be in FQL or Graph form. I would really like to search by URL, and not have a spaghetti line of results of non official pages like the link below.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com&type=page

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm not even sure how you arrived at the first id.

Comment: It's a FQL:

SELECT url,id,type,site FROM object_url WHERE url = http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: "SELECT url,id,type,site FROM object_url WHERE url = stackoverflow.com" would throw error. Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20url%2Cid%2Ctype%2Csite%20FROM%20object_url%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20stackoverflow.com

Comment: This FQL statement never fails with access_token. Throws error only when domain doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the page id, 24121414888 at your example, you should no problem to request https://graph.facebook.com/11239244970 **unless** it's a **restricted** page. The restricted require a **User Access Token** instead of APP access token to verify the caller fulfill a requirement(age, demographic...etc)

As documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/:

> To read a Page you need:
>
> - an app or user access token for public and non-demographically     restricted pages
> - a user access_token for restricted pages that the     current user is able to view (no special permissions required)